# Besides Float and Fixnum, are there any other objects that can't be created with *.new?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I have learned that `Fixnum` objects and `Float` objects don't have an explicit constructor that you can call.

This is because (and I am assuming this is done for efficiency)

> Assignment does not alias Fixnum objects. There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value 
>   http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html

I have noticed that `Float`s do not have an explicit constructor either. The reasoning is presumably the same.

Are there any other types of objects that can not be created with `Class.new`?

Please exclude `block`s and `lambda`s from the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess immediate values are like that: `true`, `false`, `nil`.

Comment: Just for clarity, Floats don't have immediate value  correct?

Comment: @LukeP, in older versions of Ruby, `Float`s were not immediates. Now they are. In the Ruby source, immediate `Float`s are referred to as "flonums", presumably by analogy to "fixnums".

Comment: @AlexD So, is it safe to say that any object that can't be constructed with "new" has immediate value?

Comment: @LukeP, in the Ruby core library, that might be the case. But you can undefine `new` for any class, and that doesn't make it an immediate. Only a few classes which are hard-coded into the interpreter can be immediates. And they can only be made immediate because *all object state can be encoded in a single machine word*. If there are other classes which are frequently used, and all their state would fit in a single machine word, they could also profitably be made immediates (by modifying the interpreter).

Comment: I'm told this will also be on the test: "On which objects having immediate values, if any, can one define methods?".

Answer (score 1):

`Symbol` is an object and does not have a `new` method.

Comment: The methods that you create normally are not `method` objects, but can be turned into `method` objects by passing the method name as a symbol to the `method()` function.

Comment: Edited. ```Method.is_a? Object``` returned true, guess I misinterpreted that.